# Flutter Checkbox did not work in AlertDialog

Tags: flutter

I am doing a checkbox in AlertDialog. I want the user to tick the checkbox before upload. My problem is if I set the variable as false the checkbox will **not change to true or change back to false**. Here is my code:

```
bool _isChecked = false;

List<String> _texts = [
 "I have confirm the data is correct",
 "I have agreed to terms and conditions.",
];

showConfirmationDialog(BuildContext context){
      AlertDialog alert=AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Confirmation'),
        content: 
        ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        children: _texts.map((text) => CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text(text),
            value: _isChecked,
            onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
            _isChecked = val;           
              });
            },
          )).toList(),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 300, 
            child:RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () => upload(context), 
              child:Text('Upload'),
            )
          )
        ],
      );
      showDialog(barrierDismissible: false,
        context:context,
        builder:(BuildContext context){
          return alert;
        },
      );
  }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: bool _isChecked = false;
it should before the build method

Comment: thank you for your reply, I put it before build method.

Comment: you need statefulBuilder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need stateful widget because showDialog can't change state.

Following code help you to understand more.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  var currentSection;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showConfirmationDialog(context);
            },
            child: Text("data"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  showConfirmationDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CustomDialog();
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomDialogState createState() => _CustomDialogState();
}

class _CustomDialogState extends State<CustomDialog> {
  List<bool> _isChecked = [false, false];
  bool canUpload = false;
  List<String> _texts = [
    "I have confirm the data is correct",
    "I have agreed to terms and conditions.",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Confirmation'),
      content: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: _texts.length,
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                          title: Text(_texts[index]),
                          value: _isChecked[index],
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _isChecked[index] = val;
                              canUpload = true;
                              for (var item in _isChecked) {
                                if (item == false) {
                                  canUpload = false;
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
            width: 300,
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: canUpload
                  ? () {
                      print("upload");
                    }
                  : null,
              child: Text('Upload'),
            ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, now can be check or no check but why I press the first checkbox both checkbox will tick

Comment: Create another variable _isChecked and  asign to another checkbox.

Comment: now the checkbox can work already, but can I ask you one more question? Like the question above, I say I want user to tick the checkbox before upload, but I do the condition at onChanged(val) {}. Why it cannot work?

Comment: I didn't understand what you ask for. Can be more clear? I commented upload. Un comment it.

Comment: I want to make sure two checkboxes is tick then just can upload(), if not cannot press the button

Comment: You could also just create a stateful Checkbox (the same way as above) instead of the whole Alert. Ensure that the bools are global and accessible to the widget. Then include it as part of the Alert in the other stateful build.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool _isChecked = false;

List<String> _texts = [
 "I have confirm the data is correct",
 "I have agreed to terms and conditions.",
];      

showConfirmationDialog(BuildContext context) {
        showDialog(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Confirmation'),
                  content: ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    children: _texts
                        .map((text) => CheckboxListTile(
                              activeColor: Colors.pink,
                              title: Text(text),
                              value: _isChecked,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isChecked = val;
                                });
                              },
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 300,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          onPressed: () => () {
                            debugPrint("upload image");
                          },
                          child: Text('Upload'),
                        ))
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      }
```

Comment: hi with this answer when i check one checkbox both of them get checked. how can i solve it so that only 1 can be checked i will have the value of the checked answer thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

inside the class add

```
void isChecked(bool newValue) => setState(() {
    _isChecked = newValue;

    if (_isChecked) {
      //something here
    } else {
      // change value here
    }
  });

//in checkbox 

  onChanged: (val) {
            isChecked(val);
                    }
```

I hope it's working

Comment: thank you for your reply, I try and add if (_isChecked) {
      _isChecked = true;
    } else {
      _isChecked = false;
    }     but it also did not change

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the alert dialog state.
If we are using a StatefullBuilder in a showModelBottomSheet, The context of the page will work fine from the showModelBottomSheet. But the Aler dialog will not change while setState is calling.
This is because the AlerDialog needs a stateful class.
Note: the State of showModelBottomSheet and an alert Dialog are not equal.
Hope the following code will help.

```
 ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () => showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext contex) {
return EnterUPIBOX();
}),
child: Text('UPI ID'),
),
```

//The alert dialog will inherit from statefulWidget.

```
class EnterUPIBOX extends StatefulWidget {
  const EnterUPIBOX({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EnterUPIBOX> createState() => _EnterUPIBOXState();
}

class _EnterUPIBOXState extends State<EnterUPIBOX> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return AlertDialog(
title: Text('CheckBox'),
actions:[ Checkbox(
value: check,
onChanged: (value) {
setState(() {
check = !check;
});
}
),
]
),
}
}
```